# Creating header in a word document using <Header> in java

Tags: java, html, header, footer

I am trying to add header to the documnet using below java code,
 The header tag works fine, if I save as .html, but not working when i save as .doc.. when i tried saving as .docx , the file is not opening in word.

```
      fw1.flush();
      //fw1.write(str);
      fw1.write("<html><body>");
      fw1.write("<header align = 'center'>My header</header><table><thead><tr><td>Your header goes here</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Page body in here -- as long as it needs to be</td></tr></tbody>   <tfoot><tr><td>Your footer goes here</td></tr></tfoot></table>");
      fw1.write("</body></html>");
      fw1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing a word doc using java isn't the most straightforward thing to do. Most folks will use c# or vba to do this. You could try out docx4j  (http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-complex-word-docx) though if you really want to use java!

Comment: Currently, I have a java code, which writes a lot of dynamic content to a word using html tags. My requirement is to add a header and footer in all the pages of the word document.

Comment: So the word doc you are generating is reading html tags.. That's not really what word was made to do.. so I guess I don't have an answer :( If you check out the solution in C# (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178795.aspx) you might be convinced to switch over.